# Existe algum controle contra votos negativos em série?

Tags: debate, comportamento, voto-contra, votos, serial-voting

Alguém acordou inspirado em me negativar :)

Eu já abri uma questão sobre isso, outras pessoas também e as respostas são sempre as mesmas... Não sou o único que crê em votos motivados por *picuinha*.

Cada um vota em UP ou DOWN, mas qual o controle contra este tipo de voto?
Os DOWN geralmente são sem motivos, são criticas **não construtivas**.

A votação é a unica forma de manter o bom andamento da comunidade.
Ninguém ganha dinheiro respondendo, então a unica coisa que acho que deva ser revista, é a forma de DOWN vote, porque desmotiva saber que o cara vota em série e vai ficar tudo na mesma...

Dei um print nos votos em série.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando voto em série é detectado, o sistema lhe devolve a reputação.

Comment: E quantos são considerados em serie?

Comment: É segredo, o algoritmo não é público, só os devs sabem como funciona.

Comment: Mas tá claro que é voto em série, os 3 foram dados em apenas 57 segundos o.O

Comment: Provavelmente o sistema prevê voto intercalado de user, e não sequencia para o mesmo, muito menos a data... votos em respostas antigas não são users recentes que caíram de paraquedas.

Comment: TKS :) eu sempre uso <br>

Comment: Saberemos amanhã se o sistema reverteu os votos ou não. Seja como for, os moderadores estão analisando a situação.

Comment: Como ficou isso?

Comment: [Igual](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13412/papa-charlie?tab=reputation). Embora o algoritmo não seja público. Eu dúvido que 3 ~ 5 votos serão o suficiente para ser detectado/revertido.

Comment: Normalmente dou um positivo num tópico alheio qualquer quando vejo que houve alguma injustiça, mesmo que eu não ganhe nada com isso. Se os usuários não fossem egoístas e egocêntricos, poderíamos ter um ambiente mais justo e reduzir ou eliminar essas mediocridades. Não perderíamos mais tempo discutindo isso e teríamos mais tempo para desenvolver coisas mais interessantes.

Comment: Agora que percebi a data desses posts... o formato das datas é muito confuso.. Seria melhor o padrão  ISO 8601

Answer (score 4):

Não sei como funciona a reversão, mas a lista com as 3 respostas -2 continua, mas acho que alguém deu UP-VOTE nelas, pois subiram. Se quem negativou tivesse desfeito, os itens -2 iriam sumir ou mudar para (+)?

É tanta *picuinha*, que alem de votarem em (-) em mim, votaram em (+) nas outras respostas para eu descer. Vi cada questão pela versão cache do google ontem.
Não critico a escolha, cada um vota na resposta que julgar melhor, mas votar em uma resposta só para a outra descer é muita *falta de civilidade*.

O algorítimo deveria levar em conta a relação da sequência de VOTO de quem vota e quem recebe, seria mais fácil encontrar um padrão votos em se série.

Enfim, agradeço a atenção dada.
Obrigado a todos.

---

### Atualizando

+6 / -30 | 3 horas atrás | 2 eventos | Votos a favor em série revertidos
Desfez os (- +), achei que tinha desfeito apenas os (+).
Por mim não tem problema não, é o justo! :)

Só gostaria de saber se foi rodado após eu abrir a questão ou se o sistema pegou por conta própria. Mera curiosidade para evitar ter que comunicar caso/quando ocorrer novamente.

Comment: Você teria que ver algo assim na sua página de reputação: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vJGgQ.png (nesse caso, foi algum fã que votou + em 8 respostas minhas)

Comment: Não há nada de `reversal`. Foi algum bom samaritano então.

Comment: Bons samaritanos, maus samaritanos, THIS IS SPARTA! quero dizer, THIS IS THE INTERNET! :P

Comment: LOL - INTERNET SERIOUS BUSINESS :)

Comment: Falando em LOL, fiquei chocado ao saber que existe o [LOLCODE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238765/we-would-like-formatting-for-lolcode) ;)

Comment: Também desconhecia. Levando em conta a tradução de `LOL`, eu não me atrevo a usá-lo :)

Comment: Gosto bastante de [LOLPython](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2007/06/01/lolpython.html) e mais de [LOLCode.net](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/6/LOLCodenet-Now-your-LOLCats-can-use-the-CLR) que o [original](http://lolcode.org/)

Comment: PS2: considerando o tamanho do nosso site atual, suspeito que seja inclusive possível identificar quem deu os downvotes. Mas não recomendo porque acredito que irá ter um efeito mais negativo que positivo.